# New line in MapInfo SQL Select

Tags: mapinfo, sql

Is there a character I need to use to state a new line in the MapInfo SQL Select box (e.g like ; in SQL Management Studio) or is this not possible. The highlighted (yellow) area is where the new line begins.

[image]

Comment: btw, I think you are missing either AND or OR where you have highlighted it with yellow

Comment: Hi Pete, I'm not sure if I explained this properly but where the gap is I want it to be a 'new' query, aka so each query would be returned as a new line in the selection table

Comment: I don't follow. Normally each record in the result will be a record in the input table. Or each record can be a grouped set of values from the input table. Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to build a massive query to return the average of a column between certain values. I have now realised I have WAY too many queries to run (~29,000) so I have cheated a little and populated a csv with the query as each line: http://i.imgur.com/8RhjvT5.png then using MapBasic I have it run the query for each row in the table and append the results to a new table: http://i.imgur.com/e6JKtTW.png

Comment: Using something other than MapInfo to perform these SQL queries would probably be much more efficient but I had to find a way that involved the current skills I have, I think asking for some SQL training from my employer next is a must

Comment: Alan, that's not cheating - that's getting things done :-) I would probably have ended up doing the same or similar thing. One recommendation is to use the "NoSelect" keyword in queries like these where you don't need the result highlighted or selected into the Selection. MIght even speed up the query a bit

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ctrl + Enter to insert new lines in the fields to make it easier to read the query in the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but try one of these:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085662/new-line-in-sql-query

Explanation:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/01/sql-server-difference-between-line-feed-n-and-carriage-return-r-t-sql-new-line-char/